# Map in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

hi guys i am trying to MAp functionality to my app and yes iam new to map handaling in android.I know there are lot of examples and tutorials  and had gone many of them but when i run my app in device or  simulator it giving me a blank file.

I am using build in  default  Map activity and only added the keys but it is not working.

Can Any only help me here

[image]

Comment: what you tried so far ? code?

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya-> i try to run the default map application and just added the key that i had generated  through google console...in emulator it give me e/cutils-trace error opening trace file permission denied (13) android studio google map error

Comment: Did you activate the service in Google Developer Console? Also, note that you must have couple of permission in your manifest file, SHA1 and API key. For more information with regards to blank map check this: http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/

Answer (score -1):

it is working but your key is for release version as far as i know. just build an APK and it should work

Comment: ok so the key i build is for the release version means i can not build and run  it on actual device via android studio...

Comment: you are running it on debug mode i think, just make an apk on release version and then install it